# How to redirect to new state in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am developing SPA application in Angularjs. This is my first application in Angularjs. I have two master pages. In first master page there is one tab when i click on that tab i want to redirect to another master page. I am using UI routing in Angularjs. I completed Login and registration modules but these modules should come in second master page but i have it in first master page now.

Below is my index.html first master page file.

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a ui-sref="Registration.mainRegistration">{{ 'Registration' | translate }}</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="Registration.Login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">{{ 'Careers' | translate }}</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">{{ 'Offers & Deals' | translate }}</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">{{ 'Financial' | translate }}</a> </li>
```

This is the first page loads. There is one Financial tab in the above file. When i click on that tab all my above master page disappears and in that place new master page should come. 
Below is my App.js

```
 var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router', 'toastr']);
   app.config(function ($stateProvider,
                        $urlRouterProvider, 
                        $translateProvider, 
                        $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

     $stateProvider
       .state('Registration', {
       abstract: true,
       url: '/Registration',
       templateUrl: 'Registration/placeholder.html',
       controller: 'MainRegistration'
     });
    //there are other states also.
```

I am in the initial stage of development. So May I know this can be achieved? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `$urlRouterProvider` has been declared twice in `app.config`

Comment: Yeah. I removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole you are using Master Page , which means you are using two different layouts , with same `<ul><li></li>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your state should not contain **abstract: true**. Abstract states are usually created when you want a parent view and create nested views.

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router', 'toastr']);
   app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

     $stateProvider
        .state('registration', {
         url: '/registration',
         templateUrl: 'Registration/registration.html',
         controller: 'RegistrationController'
        })
        .state('login', {
         url: '/login',
         templateUrl: 'Registration/login.html',
         controller: 'LoginController'
        });
```

Refer the states in ui-sref as below:

```
/All css,js and angular references.
    <script src="ForgotPassword/ForgotPasswordController.js"></script>
    <script src="ForgotPassword/ResetPasswordController.js"></script>
    <script src="ForgotPassword/OTPVerificationController.js"></script>
    <script src="ForgotPassword/ChangePasswordController.js"></script>
    //header 
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="registration">{{ 'Registration' | translate }}</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">{{ 'Careers' | translate }}</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">{{ 'Offers & Deals' | translate }}</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">{{ 'Financial' | translate }}</a> </li>
   </ul>
  <div ui-view></div>
    //Footer
```

Create the registration.html and login.html under Registration folder. Create the controller files RegistrationController and LoginController

Comment: Thanks.   <li><a href="#">{{ 'Financial' | translate }}</a> </li> Here where i should redirect?

Comment: you should create another state for that and refer that state name in ui-sref. If it is an external link other than your angular page, just use that url in href.

Comment: Thanks for your work. Should i use ui-view anywhere? But i want new state without above links. I mean new page i want to redirect. I will create plunker to understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes, you should have at least one ui-view. The templates will be rendered in the ui-view

Comment: This is my plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/m57BI5pivGzXD9UtwVtm?p=preview There is one Financial Report tab. When i click on that page i want to redirect to new page with secondmasterpage.html

Comment: Plunker cannot access the angular library. If you look at the console, you can see the error. Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/m57BI5pivGzXD9UtwVtm?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: sorry. I will create new one.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/q052NBVqTNGXVNkLLfvp?p=preview. This is page first loads When  i click on Financial tab i want to load Secondmasterpage.html.

Comment: I changed the URL to call https as https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js. Then registration link started working. Please check the plunker now.

Comment: Thanks, My problem is that when i click on Finacial tab completely i want secondmasterpage.     <li><a href="#">Financial Reports</a> </li> wheever i click on current master page i do not want to appear. Plunker i created just to show.

Comment: See it now. Create a new state in Main.js with the Seconmasterpage.html as template URL. refer that state name in the link <li><a ui-sref="financial>Financial Reports</a> </li>.

Comment: Thanks. Did u update plunker?But that state will load in  <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div> of index.html right?